# Testing collision ONLY between two objects using Unity. (If possible)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've recently dived into Unity and I've been playing around with the tools Unity provides. I'm experienced in making my own little 2D game engines for fun but decided to try and see what Unity has to offer.

I'm making a simple bullet hell game but when implementing collision I noticed that Unity's "OnTriggerEnter" method tests collision on everything. I can't find a built in way of testing collision from just the bullet to the player. The solutions I found online was inside the method to test if the collision was the desired object. But I can imagine that this is very performant for 100s of projectiles to test collision on each other.

Before I do my own collision detection I wanted to make sure there's not some perfect method out there that I just can't find. I find myself often reinventing the wheel for something that already exists in Unity.

Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1520676/view.html), you can put the bullets and player on different layers then just disable collision between all objects on the bullet layer using the Layer Collision Matrix.

Comment: That's perfect! This fixes more than just that issue. Thank you!